# Java print double scientific notation, less digits

Tags: java

Right now, Java is printing `7.1781566186590595E-6`. I want it to print `7.17E-6`.

I searched this up, but I only found how to reduce digits without scientific notation (so it will end up like `0.00` because the number is small).

Comment: Did you try `%.2g` (I don't have anything to test right now)?

Comment: ? do you mean put that in DecimalFormatter or something

Comment: Maybe using [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Use format specifier ["%.3g"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

```
float f = 7.1781566186590595E-6f;
System.out.format("%.3g", f);
```

Output

```
7.18e-06
```

Note, you mentioned `7.17E-6` in your question as desired output, but that's not correctly rounded - should be `7.18e-06`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format` method to format and create your `String`, than you can use it like any `String`.

Therefore the `"%.3g"` format should be used like this:

```
double myDouble = 1/12345678d;
System.out.println(String.format("%.3g", myDouble));
```

Will result in: `8,10e-08`.

**Note:** The ".3" in the format specifies the precision. In case you want more or less digits you can simply change the number to your needs like e.g. `"%.5g"` in case you want two extra digits.
You can also exchange the small "g" with "G" it'll print a capital "E" instead of the small "e".

In case you prefer the "." instead of the "," as a separator you can additionally explicitly specify the local to be used in the formatter like the following:

```
double myDouble = 1/12345678d;
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.3g", myDouble));
```

Will result in: `8.10e-08`.

More information can be found in the JavaDoc of `String.format` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

---

**EDIT:**

Interesting in your case:

When you use the format string as above (with the 'g') `"%.3g"` it'll round your value in the mathematical correct way. When you change the format string and use it with an 'e' `"%.3e"` it'll not round it and treat your number as a literal:

Code:

```
double myDouble = 7.1781566186590595E-6d;
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.3e", myDouble));
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.3g", myDouble));
```

Result:

```
7.178e-06 // using "%.3e" => literal, therefore not rounded
7.18e-06  // using "%.3g" => rounded
```